# Sturm-Liouville problem: How to calculate the eigenfunctions of a periodic system?

Tags: periodic-functions, wave-equation, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Consider the following Sturm-Liouville equation
$$\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}+\frac{\omega^2}{c^2(x)}y(x)=0,$$
where
$$c(x)=\begin{cases}
c_1, & x \le l \\
c_2, & x > l.
\end{cases}$$
The system is periodic in $x$ with period $L>l$, i.e. $y(x)=y(x+L)$. The boundary conditions are given by $y(0)=y(L)$, $dy/dx|_{x=0}=dy/dx|_{x=L}$. Assume continuity of $y$ and $dy/dx$. Do you know how to calculate the eigenfunctions, $y_n$, and eigenfrequencies $\omega_n$? If $c_1=c_2=c$, then the eigenfunctions are given by
$$y_n = \exp(ik_nx),$$
where
$$k_n=\frac{\omega_n}{c},$$
$$\omega_n = n\pi\frac{c}{L},$$
where $n$ is an integer which can be negative.

Comment: so Sturm-Liouville equation is a 2nd order diff equ that looks like (f(x)y')'+g(x)y=0?

Comment: Yes. In this equation $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\omega^2/c^2(x)$.

Comment: An version of definition says g(x) is $g_1(x)+\lambda g_2(x)$, that doesn't change the inherent property of the ODE but just turn it into a 'series' of similar ODE right? Would you like to give a (most common) example of it?

Comment: Any function can be written as $g_1(x)+\lambda g_2(x)$. The $\lambda$ gives the eigenvalues. It is useful to express it explicitly since regular SL problems only have solutions for discrete eigenvalues. The simplest SL problem would be the equation in the OP with $c_1=c_2$.

Comment: So the simplest case is like $y''+\omega^2y=0$ with solution like $Ce^{i\omega x}$

Comment: Yes. Note that solutions only exist for discrete values of $\omega$. If we were to change the boundary conditions to $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$ say, then solutions could exist for any value of $\omega$.